# Obtain value of a field in an "owning" class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is there anyway to obtain an instance of a class called in another class?
For example, if Foo class has an instance of a Bar class and a Clazz class,
is there anyway to obtain the instance of the Bar class through the Clazz class using reflection?

```
public class Foo{
  Bar b = new Bar();
  Clazz c = new Clazz();
}

public class Bar
{
   int i = 3;
}

public class Clazz
{
  //Code to get the instance of Bar running in Foo using Reflection
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "instance of `Bar` running in `Foo`", since you have not instantiated a `Foo`. And no, as it stands, `Clazz` has no knowledge of any classes that may refer to it in a field, you would have to add that.

One way to do this is via proper use of getters and keeping track of the parent object:

```
public class Foo {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    Clazz c = new Clazz(this); // be warned: `this` is not fully constructed yet.
    public Bar getB () { return b; }
}

public class Clazz {
    private final Foo owner;
    public Clazz (Foo owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public void example () {
        doSomething(owner.getB());
    }
}
```

Or, even better, since `Clazz` no longer depends on `Foo` and you don't have to worry about a partially constructed `Foo`, just pass the `Bar` to `Clazz`:

```
public class Foo {
    Bar b = new Bar();
    Clazz c = new Clazz(b); 
}

public class Clazz {
    private final Bar bar;
    public Clazz (Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
    public void example () {
        doSomething(bar);
    }
}
```

The second way more naturally indicates your actual dependencies as well (`Clazz` doesn't care that it comes from a `Foo`, it only cares about having a `Bar`).

The first way has the advantage of allowing `Foo` to change its `Bar` at any point (I noticed  you did not declare `final b` in `Foo`) and have `Clazz` be aware of the updated value; of course, that same thing can be accomplished with a `Clazz#setBar(Bar b)` without introducing a false dependency on `Foo`.

---

There isn't much need for reflection there. However, responding to your comment below, where you write:

> *The actual purpose of my question regards to a battleship tournament we are having in a CS class at my University. We are allowed to hack each other in order to find the ship deployment of our adversary.*

Unfortunately, then -- presuming your snippet is an accurate representation of the code structure -- unless `Clazz` stores an instance of the `Foo` that created it (or is a non-static inner class of a `Foo`), you are out of luck. There is no way with reflection to find the `Foo` that has that `Clazz` (and thus get the `Bar`), because reflection does not provide a means of getting a list of all instantiated `Foo`s to search through. If you know the `Foo` then you can get its `b` member, but you have to know about the `Foo` instance to begin with. You might be able to inject some clever byte code somewhere to track it though, a bit advanced but see [Java Bytecode Instrumentation](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=585), or [here for an overview](http://www.correlsense.com/blog/java-bytecode-instrumentation-an-introduction/).

You then write:

> *I have read that there is a way to find the instance of the Foo class through reflection if you know the name of the class.*

No, unfortunately (if I understand you correctly), [there is no way to get an existing instance of a `Foo` given only its class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067987/java-reflection-get-instances-of-a-given-class-found-by-entering-its-name).

> *Is there anyway for me to find the Bar class if I find the Foo class?*

If you have an instance of a `Foo`, and you know the field name is `b`, then you can do:

```
Foo theFoo = ...; // your Foo instance

Field field = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("b");
Bar theBar = (Bar)field.get(theFoo); // get field "b" value from 'theFoo'.
```

See [`Class.getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) and [`Field.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: I undesrtand what you are saying, but my example was just a general example for what I was trying to achieve. The actual purpose of my question regards to a battleship tournament we are having in a CS class at my University. We are allowed to hack each other in order to find the ship deployment of our adversary. That is the reason why I wanted to know how to get the name of a class or an instance through reflection.

Comment: Well I do know what the name of the Foo class is. I have read that there is a way to find the instance of the Foo class through reflection if you know the name of the class. Is there anyway for me to find the Bar class if I find the Foo class?

Comment: @AlanW I've updated my answer with answers to your comments as well as an example snippet.