# Getting all instances of a class

Tags: java, class, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a simple way of obtaining all object instances of a specific class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947122/is-there-a-simple-way-of-obtaining-all-object-instances-of-a-specific-class-in-j)

In java, is there any possible way to get all the instances of a certain class?

Comment: since you would be instantiating them, simply keep a (weak? does java have weak references?) reference to each instance. But I would suspect any design that required this...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a Factory static initializer when you instantiate your class ([Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) and then add each generated instance in the factory constructor to a List ...

Something like this :

```
  class MyObject {
    private static List instances = new ArrayList();

    public static MyObject createMyObject() {
    MyObject o = new MyObject();
    instances.add(new java.lang.ref.WeakReference(o));
    return o;
    }

    public static List getInstances() {
    return instances;
    }

    private MyObject() {
    // Not allowed 
    }
  }
```

Comment: A weak hash set might be a nicer collection as it cleans up such references transparently. `Set<MyObject> instances = Collections.newSetFromMap(new WeakHashMap<MyObject, Boolean>());`

Comment: This is not a viable solution for my present problem ... I want to obtain instances of third-party classes.

Answer (score 9):

Not in general. If you're using the debugger API it may be possible (I haven't checked) but you shouldn't use that *other* than for debugging.

If your design requires this, it's probably worth rethinking that design.