# How to retrieve the Applet instance

Tags: java, applet, awt

In a Java applet-application, is there a way to obtain the actual applet instance somehow? e.g. a static method or singleton that makes this available? I'm working on a project where I can't access/modify the Applet class source code so I need a way to find the current Applet instance.

The reason for this is I think I need to inspect/modify how the applet is loading resources.

Comment: Clearly, it's a Java question...

Comment: As you alluded to yourself, not helping when you have an answer hurts the site as a whole because anyone else finding this question would be mislead. Think about _that_ next time the medium of writing comments leads to crossed wires!

Comment: if you have access to an AWT/Swing component that gets added to the hierarchy you can iterate parents until you find a parent that is instanceof Applet. otherwise I think you are out of luck.
does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawingApplet extends Applet {

   private static Applet INSTANCE;

   public void init() {
      INSTANCE = this;
      // your init logic goes here;
      ....
   }

   public void paint( Graphics g ) {
     // your paint logic goes here.
   }
}
```

Why this way won't work for you?

**UPDATE 1**
If you don't have the access to your Applet sources, I'm afraid you can't catch the instance of the applet. More details are explained in this thread: [Getting all instances of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071065/getting-all-instances-of-a-class)

Comment: Ahh! :) I see it. So you need to catch your applet somehow from outside of applet instance. I'll think on it now.

Comment: Exactly. I clarified the question to make that obvious now.