# Java: Method hooking & Finding object instances

Tags: java, jvm, reverse-engineering, heap-memory, jdi

### Situation

Hi, I have 2 problems.
The situation is that I'm writing a **Java API for Windows** that also provides tools for injecting code into a process and then manipulate the target. I have already implemented the *injection-part*, for example injecting a jar into another jar. At this point my jar gets called (while the target already is at runtime) and starts in a **complete static context**.

### Goals & problems

From here I have two goals:

1. I'd like to **interact with the targets objects**, thus I need **references**. For many objects this is already possible because they provide static access to their instances. For example *awt.Frames#getFrames()* provides access to all created Frame objects. But it would be awesome if there is a possibility to get **access to arbitrary objects** on the heap. Something like '*Heap#getAllObjectInstances()*'.
2. Given an object instance, I'd like to **hook up onto arbitrary functions** of this object. For example whenever *BufferStrategy#show()* gets called, I want it to call another method first.

So I **summarize** the problems as follows:

1. How to get arbitrary object references from a static context?
2. How to hook up onto arbitrary functions?

### Remarks

What I've done so far, remarks and ideas:

1. The **JDI** (Java Debugger Interface) provides such a method via *VirtualMachine#allClasses() -> ReferenceType#instances(0)*. But the JDI needs the **target JVM** to be started with additional *debug parameter* which is **no option for me**. One could go down to **low-level** and analyze the heap with **memory tools**, but I hope someone knows a more **high-level approach**. Using the Windows API would be an option for me as I'm familiar with *JNA/JNI*, but I don't know such a tool.
2. The last resort would be to use **IAT hooking** with C-Code, a very low-level approach, I'd like to **avoid this**. As I can assume having a object reference at this point, maybe does the **Reflection API** provide a method to change an objects method? Or at least simply provide a hooking mechanism?

Be aware that changing the targeted code certainly is no option for me. And that it is already at runtime, thus ByteCode-Manipulation could also be an option.

### Scenario

A scenario where this would come in handy:
The target is a **game**, deployed as jar. It renders with a **Double-Buffer-Strategy**, using the *BufferStrategy* class. It displays the image with **BufferStrategy#show()**. We inject our jar inside the game and like to draw an overlay with additional information. For this we get an reference to the used *BufferStrategy* and hook up onto its *show*-method. So that it **calls our drawOverlay-method** everytime it gets called, then we pass back to the original *show-method*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is JVMTI agent - a native library that makes use of [JVM Tool Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html).

Agents can be attached dynamically to a running VM using the [Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/attach/).
See [VirtualMachine.loadAgentPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html#loadAgentPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

1. To get all instances of a given class use JVMTI [IterateOverInstancesOfClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#IterateOverInstancesOfClass) function.
   See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458490/jni-how-to-list-all-the-current-instances/36467422) for details.
2. To intercept a method of a foreign class you'll need JVMTI  [RetransformClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses) API. The same can be also achieved by using Java-level instrumentation API, see [Instrumentation.retransformClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses-java.lang.Class...-).

For the example of JVMTI-level method interception refer to `demo/jvmti/mtrace` from Oracle JDK demos and samples package.

Java-level instrumentation will be easier with bytecode manipulation libraries like [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy).

Comment: **JVM TI**, didn't know that one, **thanks**.

The first problem probably will be easy to solve with this API.

As with the second problem, will probably work well for future instances but I'm unsure if this approach affects already created instances. Do you know an approach that also affects them?

Comment: @Zabuza `RetransformClasses` may instrument already loaded classes, including system classes. If you modify a method, existing instances will call the modified version next time.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. I'll call back once I've found the time to implement it.