# JVM - peek at class field during Spring application runtime

Tags: java, spring, jvm, properties-file

Recently I have got a need to peek at some class field value.
The class looks somewhat like this:

```
public class Foo(){

   @Autowired
   protected MessageResolver resolver;

   protected static final String INJECTED_TEXT_PROPERTY_CODE = "code";
   protected String injectedText;

   @PostConstruct
   public void initialize() {
    injectedText = resolver.resolveMessage(INJECTED_TEXT_PROPERTY_CODE);
   }
}
```

Then I have some property source like this:

```
code=injectedCode
```

Now the difficulty of the task is that it won't be on my machine but on the client machine. Therefore ideally I need some easy command to execute which will not mess with a working system.

EDIT: The field which I want to peak is **injectedText**.

EDIT2: Most interesting solution was introduced by @apangin (jmap and dump analyzis offline). Thanks!

Comment: What about making a heap dump with `jmap` and then analyzing the dump offline?

Comment: It is possible to find instances of a particular class like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042962/java-method-hooking-finding-object-instances/38044372#38044372) but this is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @apangin suggested I used [jmap](https://blog.gceasy.io/2015/08/14/how-to-capture-heap-dump-jmap/) utility to create heap dump of my application.

Firstly I had to figure out what was my application PID. I did it with the command:

```
jps
```

Than I created a heap dump of my app ( my PID was 303):

```
jmap -dump:live,file=C:\dump.bin 303
```

Finally I analyzed heap dump with a [jhat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) utility:

```
jhat C:\dump.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

On startup of the application you need to load the property of the client machine. Look this http://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Also, you can use @Value annotation from spring to inject a property value

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

class MyClass {

   @Value("${value.from.property}")
   private String valueFromProperty;

}
```