# How I can find object by string

Tags: java, reflection

I have some object with hierarchy based on BaseSample
`abstract class BaseSample;
class Sample extends BaseSample`
Then I create one.
`Sample object = new Sample`
And then I need to create some method to find previously created object.
`BaseSample findObjectByString(String objectSampleClassName)`
It is possible to find already created object by his class name and do not create own list of BaseSample objects?
Thanks for reply.

Comment: how is your hierarchy defined? does `Sample` class contain more `Sample` objects?

Comment: You will usually prefer to create your own list. Everything else would get unreasonably tricky.

Comment: See also [Is there a simple way of obtaining all object instances of a specific class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947122/is-there-a-simple-way-of-obtaining-all-object-instances-of-a-specific-class-in-j).

Comment: What does the string you search by represent? Why not just keep a `Map<String, BaseSample>` and keep instances there?